# Question about the code for K-means Cluster Analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am studying how to carry out K-means Cluster analysis in R.
I found code from [Clustering: Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583157/clustering-quick-transfer-stage-steps-exceeded-maximum/64729057#64729057) and tried with that data. But I have a question.

In line

```
set.seed(20)
Test1<-scale(na.omit(data.matrix(testData6)[-1]))
```

I don't understand clearly the meaning of `[-1]` in `data.matrix(testData6)[-1]`. Do you want to remove the first  column (the index) of the matrix (`testData6`)? If we want to remove the first column, the code should be `data.matrix(testData6)[,-1]` right? There should has a comma before -1, right?

But, if there has no comma, the result of `data.matrix(testData6)[-1]` just delete the first element of that matrix. So, why it need to delete the first element?

Comment: Likely it's just a mistake in that code.

Comment: You are correct, but since a data frame is a list, R will interpret a single index number as a column so `[-1]` and `[, -1]` will both remove the first column while `[-1, ]` will remove the first row. I think your code is easier to understand if you include the comma.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am new to R, but I tried both  [-1]  and  [,-1], the result is different, I mean the figure of elbow result is different.@dcarlson

Comment: Thanks@KarolisKoncevičius, but if you see the data he used(testData6), the first 3 columns (Month, State,City) are not  numerical data, so why just remove the first column?